# Why table with JSON results is not displayed?

Tags: jquery, json, html-table

The code in success is not displaying a table with JSON results. I know it's this particular part of the code because I tested whether JSON is returned and displayed directly in div tags and that works. Now I want to display in a table which sits inside a div container. Also is it possible to include some styling to the table using attributes but I assume this may need to be done in a none standard way inside a jQuery dynamically created table?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    datetype: "json",
    data: {sdate: selecteddate, sday:day}, // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function(data)
    {                        
        $('#records').append("<table></table>");
        recordtable=$('#records').appendchildren();
        $.each(data, function(index,item){
            recordtable.append('<tr><td>' +item.NurseID+'</td><td>'+item.AvailableDate+'</td><td>'+item.Early+'</td><td>'+item.Late+'</td><td>'+item.Night+'</td><td>'+item.Full+'</td></tr>');
        });                                                  
    }
});
```

Comment: An example of `data` would be helpful. Probably it is empty? Or invalid for your script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `.appendchildren()` is a jQuery method so `recordtable` will not be usable. Set your recordtable variable like this and it should work:

```
var recordtable = $("#records table");
```

You can style the table using CSS either in a stylsheet or on the fly with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Thanks jarbaugh. Does #recordstable have to exist in html before hand or would your declaration create it?

Comment: table is a child of #records, which you inserted into the DOM in the first line of your success handler. In the next line, you use the statement that I wrote to assign the new table to the variable recordtable. jQuery uses CSS selectors and $("#records table") means "get the table that is inside of the element with the id 'records'"

Comment: $('#thediv').append("<table id='thetable'></table>");
                        tab=$('#thetable');
                                               
                        $.each(data, function(index,item){
                             tab.append('<tr><td>' +item.NurseID+'</td><td>'+item.AvailableDate+'</td><td>'+item.Early+'</td><td>'+item.Late+'</td><td>'+item.Night+'</td><td>'+item.Full+'</td></tr>');
                           });